# GNU Parallel and Python atexit

Tags: python, gnu-parallel, atexit

I was trying to run a python script with GNU parallel. Everything seems to work, except for the atexit routine used inside the python script. It seems, after ctrl+c, parallel is killing the python process without giving python a chance to call the registered atexit routine.
How to make parallel a bit nicer towards the child processes?

Here is an example to show the behaviour.

test_signal.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import sys
import atexit

def cleanup():
    print('cleanup called', flush=True)

atexit.register(cleanup)

time.sleep(60)
print('completed process', sys.argv[1])
```

Tested with the command:

```
chmod +x test_signal.py
./test_signal.py 1 # this works as expected when using ^C
parallel -j 4 ./test_signal.py {} ::: $(seq 1 12) # this one does not
```

Comment: does it run the cleanup when you let the timer run out? (wait 60 seconds)

Comment: Yes. It does. With or without parallel, cleanup is called in normal exit (no ctrl+c).

Comment: Try `killall -HUP parallel` instead of Ctrl-C

Comment: Apparently parallel is a perl script. So killall -HUP parallel reported 'parallel: no process found'. I tried kill -HUP <pid>.  It stopped with message 'Hangup'. But no cleanup.

Comment: Ok, sorry. We'll have to wait for Ole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU Parallel kills jobs as specified in `--termseq`. It defaults to:

```
TERM,200,TERM,100,TERM,50,KILL,25
```

So SIGTERM, wait 200 ms, SIGTERM, wait 100 ms, SIGTERM, wait 50 ms, SIGKILL, wait 25 ms. If the process dies while waiting, GNU Parallel ignores the rest of the sequence - no need to kill a dead horse.

Change `--termseq` to the signals you want sent and the time between them.

CTRL-C sends SIGINT, so this should work:

```
# Give 1 second to clean up, then kill
parallel --termseq INT,1000,KILL,25 ...
```

Just be aware that you will not see the output unless you use `--ungroup`.

Comment: Great, it worked. I had tried `--termseq` before. But ungroup was missing. Thanks a lot.